# Sql change time

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I need to find out how many days have passed between two datetimes. The catch is, if the first datetime is after 8pm eastern, i need to treat it as occuring following morning.

It seems to me the best way to handle this is to simply change the first datetime, then find the time between the two but I am unsure how to do this. For example, if a date is 2016-1-1 12:00:00, no change is made. If a date is 2016-1-1 21:00:00, the new date is 2016-1-2 08:00:00.

Does anyone have a solution? Any direction would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are all dates/times in the same Time Zone?

Comment: You can't just ask for a solution. What have you tried? What did/didn't work? Which flavour of sql are you using? You will most probably not get any good answers, since there are too many unknowns in your question and you are not showing any effort in trying to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41439/14)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table tbl(
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  t0 datetime,
  t1 datetime
);

insert into tbl(t0,t1) values
('2016-03-01 12:00:00', '2016-08-15 16:50:00'),
('2016-05-15 20:00:00', '2016-08-15 16:50:00'),
('2016-06-30 19:00:00', '2016-08-15 16:50:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select tbl.* 
     , datediff(
         date(if(time(t1) >= '20:00:00', date_add(t1, interval 1 day), t1)),
         date(if(time(t0) >= '20:00:00', date_add(t0, interval 1 day), t0))
     ) as diff   
from tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41439/14/0)**:

```
| id |                      t0 |                       t1 | diff |
|----|-------------------------|--------------------------|------|
|  1 | March, 01 2016 12:00:00 | August, 15 2016 16:50:00 |  167 |
|  2 |   May, 15 2016 20:00:00 | August, 15 2016 16:50:00 |   91 |
|  3 |  June, 30 2016 19:00:00 | August, 15 2016 16:50:00 |   46 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server how about doing something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, yourDateField) > 20 THEN
 Cast(Cast(Cast(DATEADD(dd, 1, yourdatefield) as smalldatetime) as varchar)
 + ' 08:00:00'as datetime) else yourdatetime END
```

**The above is more pseudo code.** I need to refine it when I get access to SSMS. The concept being that you do a SELECT CASE checking the hour of the time you want to compare. If it > 20 (8pm) then manually parse and create tomorrow's date at 8:00 am else show the date.

ASSUMPTION: All time zones are the same

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this via suing Microsoft access.For example In Microsoft access 2010 follow this step :
   1. Search for option called 'create'

2. In that option select 'query wizard' and once you select you will get your data with date.

for example , if Contain values that fall within a date range

> ## 2/2/2006# and <#2/4/2006

Returns records where the transactions took place between Feb 2, 2006 and Feb 4, 2006.

You can also use the Between operator to filter for a range of values, including the end points. For example, Between #2/2/2006# and #2/4/2006# is the same as >=#2/2/2006# and <=#2/4/2006# .

Comment: The assumption is SQL server since SQL is the tag